# How to refer to "The Internet" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice

I have seen at least 3 ways to refer to "The Internet" : la reto, interreto, la interreto.

What is the most common way to write "The Internet"? Are some of them deserving to be avoided?

Comment: There is also [TTT](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTT), although that article makes a distinction between this and the "Internet". But in my opinion, the way people use the word "Internet" in many cases overlaps with WWW.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*The Internet* is *La Interreto*, but just as *Internet* in English has transformed over the years to be lowercase as *internet*, the same applies to Esperanto, so today I would recommend calling it *interreto* (literally inter-web), which is also the word we officially teach in Duolingo's Esperanto course for English speakers. Note that in English, this exact same trend also happened to *e-mail*. Today style guides recommend us to just write *email*.

*Reto* just means *web*, but *la reto* could also be translated as *the net.* But just like in English this could also mean any kind of web like a spider's web or even metaphorically like a web of connections between people. *Online* (as in "talk to me online") is usually best translated as *rete* (literally: webly) although "I am online" would best be translated to *Mi estas enreta.*

On the same topic, you also might find an interesting sidenote that in the early days of the internet, the *World Wide Web* (WWW) was often translated as the *Tut-Tera Teksaĵo* (TTT, literally: Total Earth Textile-Thing). This has since fallen out of use, but you will occasionally encounter it on old Esperanto websites.

Comment: I think I still say _TTT-ejo_  for website sometimes, haha. Now of course it's "retejo". I don't believe I've ever seen "interretejo"--to my mind that would be an internet cafe or something.

Answer (score 0):

In (semi)formal contexts, `(La) Interreto` seems to be most preferred.

`(La) Reto` refers to `(The) Net`. This is most common.

---

Generally, these two terms are interchangeable. Using `la` can help discern between some other large networks and the Internet, if the meaning is contextually ambiguous.

Comment: Your last comment reminds me of _the Internets_ said from a famous person.